# Libssl-dev installation error

Tags: pi-2

I have been trying to install libssl-dev on rpi2B with the following version of raspbian - *Linux raspberrypi 4.1.7-v7+ #817 SMP PREEMPT Sat Sep 19 15:32:00 BST 2015 armv7l*

I have already tried sudo apt-get update/upgrade but the problem is still not resolved. I am attaching a snippet of the messages in the terminal during installation.

> sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
>
> Reading package lists... Done
>
> Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done
>
> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested
> an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution
> that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved
> out of Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the
> situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  libssl-dev : Depends:
> libssl1.0.0 (= 1.0.1e-2+rvt+deb7u11) but 1.0.1e-2+rvt+deb7u17 is to be
> installed
>
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Related link : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1982344

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, that I couldn't get libssl-dev even after an apt-get upgrade.

However, once I did another apt-get update AFTER running the apt-get upgrade ... then it worked.

No idea why, but there you have it.